# Launch background win32 console application in UWP

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, uwp, desktop-bridge

A Win32 console application can be launched by

```
create_task(Windows::ApplicationModel::FullTrustProcessLauncher::LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync()).then([&] {});
```

and

```
await Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync();
```

following AppService Bridge Sample. A commond window is displayed even I don't want to input/output anything. I don't find any parameter like SW_HIDE in CreateProcess. How to launch background win32 console application in UWP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the project settings for the Win32 process, change the output type from Console Application to Windows Application, like this:

[image]

Thanks,
Stefan Wick - Windows Developer Platform

Comment: I believe, the OP wants to launch an external command line application they cannot change, and prevent the system from allocating and/or showing the command line window.

Comment: It's not an external component, the component is part of the same package and controlled by the app developer. In the sample that component is set to output type =Console Application. I actually wrote that sample and I did that intentionally so that you see what's going on :-). I understand for the real world you don't want the console, so you can just change the output type to Windows Application. For reference, this is the sample the OP is referring to: https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/AppServiceBridgeSample

Comment: I'm not convinced that the OP's ultimate goal is to run the sample code without allocating a console. They appear to be using that as a starting point, but are looking for a general solution to the question: How do I launch a command line application without allocating and/or showing a console window?

Comment: What you are saying is not supported/possible from UWP in the first place. The only way to do it by launching a Win32 process from your own package, which is what the sample demonstrates. The question from the OP is how to not have the command window for that one, and this is what I answered. Now from that process they can then launch other processes as well (as it runs outside the app container), but first they need to overcome the issue explained in the question that I answered above.

Comment: Again, this is not entirely convincing. Just because this external command line tool is part of the same application package does not imply, that they own the code or can change it at will. I'm pretty positive, that a developer working on the Visual Studio IDE cannot just walk in and change the subsystem of *cl.exe*, even though the IDE and compiler are part of the same installer (which is analogous to an application package). Anyway, only the OP can know what they need.

Comment: Changing the output type is the only way to solve it. In case they don't have access to it then there is no other way. There is no other answer :-)